# steeltoe serilog dynamic logger not working after migrating to steeltoe 3.0

Tags: vmware, asp.net-core-3.1, pcf, steeltoe

I was using steeltoe 2.4.3 in my .net core 3.1 application. Recently I updated steeltoe packages to v3.0.1 and it looks like logs are not coming in serilog format. I am not able to figure out what is wrong. I do have the serilog configuration in my appsettings like below.

```
  {
    "management": {
    "endpoints": {
      "path": "/myexample/cloudfoundryapplication",
      "cloudfoundry": {
        "validateCertificates": false
      },
      "actuator": {
        "exposure": {
          "include": [ "*" ],
          "exclude": [ "env", "refresh" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Steeltoe": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Trace",
        "Args": {
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Program.cs is like below

```
    public static class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Activity.DefaultIdFormat = ActivityIdFormat.W3C;
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
       
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .AddCloudFoundryConfiguration()
                .ConfigureLogging((builderContext, loggingBuilder) =>
                {
                    // Add Serilog Dynamic Logger 
                    loggingBuilder.AddDynamicSerilog();
                })
                .AddCloudFoundryActuators()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

My .csproj looks iike below.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;*.yml">
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
   </None>
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Trace" Version="2.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" Version="1.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Extensions.Logging.DynamicSerilogCore" Version="3.0.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Management.CloudFoundryCore" Version="3.0.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundryCore" Version="3.0.1" />
 </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

`AddDynamicSerilog` doesn't (currently) add a console sink, try updating your code to look like this:

```
AddDynamicSerilog(new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console())
```

[This PR](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Steeltoe/pull/492) will result in the Console sink being added automatically if no configuration is provided, and it will probably ship in Steeltoe 3.0.2 (no ETA yet)